# Meaning of "about to [do something]" when it refers to somebody's action

Tags: meaning, phrases

> I am about to launch a start-up company.

Would the sentence be understood as *I am intending to launch a start-up company*, or *I am close to launch a start-up company*?

In a sentence like *the ceremony was about to begin*, I would understand that the ceremony was close to begin; is that the most common meaning assigned to sentences like *I am about to launch a start-up company*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "about to" implies that the action described is in the very near future - that it is on the point of happening. So, of your two alternatives,

> I am close to launching a start-up company.

most closely fits the meaning.

[Note that it's "close to launching", not "close to launch" - the "to" here belongs with "close", not to the verb, which is in gerund (verbal noun) form.]

That said, most statements about one's action in the future can be interpreted as intention - if I say "I'm about to eat my dinner", and then discover that I have no food in the house and therefore can't, I'm not necessarily lying - so your other alternative is close in meaning too - but

> I am intending to lanch a start-up company *very soon*.

would be closer still.

Comment: To complete this answer, I would add that if you say "I'm not about to" do something, it indicates that not only are you not ready, but that you have no intention of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

*I am about to do X* means *In a short time I will have done X*.

For your examples:

> The ceremony was about to begin.
>
> In a short time, the ceremony will have begun.
>
> The ceremony will begin in five minutes.

and

> I am about to launch a start-up.
>
> In a short time, I will have launched my start-up.